# Managing Stack Overflow questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

How do I close/delete questions that I have not received any conclusive feedback on?

What's the appropriate thing to do as far as the existing comments and dealing with the question itself?

Comment: It looks like you start with a priori descission that question that *have not received any conclusive feedback* whould be closed/deleted. I disagree.

Answer (score 6):

My advice: don't close them. They haven't yet had an answer that you could accept so why not leave them open. It's not like your one little question will be straining the storage resources of SO :-)

I would suggest editing the question to provide more information so that you may get more people willing to answer it.

If you can't edit it, ask another with the clarifying details, giving a pointer to the original and *explaining that you couldn't edit it* (otherwise you'll likely have the new question closed as a dupe).

Also, I would have provided a link to it in *this* question to breath some life back into it although, from your user page, I assume it's [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875653/linq2sql-insert-records-to-related-tables).

Unfortunately I can't help you with that question since I know little of LINQ. It may be that no-one has an answer (although that's unlikely).

Once you get to 50 rep, you can offer a bounty if you want to sacrifice some of your hard-earned rep for an answer. If the SO developers ever accept the proposal to allow *any user* to offer a bounty on any question (c'mon guys, this would be really useful :-), you may find someone willing to help you out.

Here's a few rep points to help you out if you want to go the bounty way.

Answer (score 3):

There is a delete button. Its light gray and right beside edit. If you have a question that has been hanging around for a while without any answers like your ""Linq2Sql Insert Records To Related Tables" question you could put a bounty on it.